# Library projects in Android Studio only work if nested in the project tree?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-studio

I'm trying to build a project dependent on `ActionbarSherlock` in Android Studio.

After much reading I've ended up having a working build, but only if I nest the ABS project inside my main project like so:

```
MainProject
MainProject\ABS (copied here and then used import module)
MainProject\MainModule (the one created by the wizard)
```

I had to edit the various Gradle files, `settings.gradle` is as follows:

```
include ':OnTop'
include ':ActionbarSherlock'
```

I fixed the dependencies in the `build.gradle` files accordingly.

This is suboptimal, I think. Surely I don't want to replicate the ABS module in every new project that uses it? What should I be doing instead?

Comment: See [How do I add a library project to the Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16639227/1693859). That guy explained step by step.

Comment: hello, any luck on this issue? did you managed to properly organize shared library projects?

Answer (score 0):

Every step are here : [How do I add a library project to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio/16639227#16639227)

If you want to more about gradle see the Google I/O conference  by Xavier Ducrohet on youtube : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCJAgPkpmR0

Comment: That solution produce a project that's like mine, with ABS embedded in the project tree (in fact i read that ansewer among many others). What i am asking is how to keep the ABS library outside the project so it can be shared among many projects.

Comment: ActionBarSherlock is a module on your project. What you want is a module which is independant. I don't know if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I searched this issue enough and finally these are my results:-

This sample project

> -> project root
>
> d:\asprojects\thisproject
>
> -> module
>
> d:\asprojects\thisproject\MyModule
>
> -> libraries
>
> d:\asprojects\lvl
>
> d:\asprojects\MyLibrary
>
> -> jars
>
> D:/asprojects/android-support-v4.jar
>
> D:/asprojects/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar

-If you want to use external (outside the project) libraries then the settings.gradle has to point to it like so:-

> settings.gradle
>
> > ```
> > include ':lvl', ':MyLibrary', ':MyModule'
> > project(':MyLibrary').projectDir = new File('D:/asprojects/MyLibrary')
> > project(':lvl').projectDir = new File('D:/asprojects/lvl')
> > ```

-Then you need to setup the build.gradle for the MyModule correctly like so:-

build.gradle

```
dependencies  
{ 
compile files('D:/asprojects/android-support-v4.jar') 
compile files('D:/asprojects/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar') 
compile project(':lvl') compile project(':MyLibrary')   
}
```

-But the IDE will not like these absolute paths and will say not found.

-But gradlw from commandline work justs fine:-

> ```
> gradlew clean
> gradlew build
> gradlew installRelease
> etc
> ```